How do i continue typing after an auto-completed pair of brackets/double quotes? ( since arrow key /end key breaks the follow )
When I type an opening bracket or double-quote in my code editor, it automatically inserts the closing bracket or quote. However, I often find myself needing to continue typing immediately after these auto-completed characters. Instead of pressing the right arrow key or manually moving the cursor, is there a more efficient way to handle this?
For example:
After typing (, the editor inserts ), but I want to continue typing outside the closing parenthesis without extra keystrokes.
Similarly, after typing ", the editor inserts the closing ", but I need to continue typing outside the quotes efficiently.
I've noticed this issue in various code editors and online coding platforms like LeetCode and CodeChef. Any tips or settings that can help improve this workflow would be greatly appreciated.
I tried using end key instead of arrow key but it equal frustating .. i also tried tab key but it is not working .

TabOut: Specifically designed to let you press Tab to jump over closing brackets, quotes, or tags.
Try this vscode extension here.
This atleast resolves this for vscode... but I suggest you just bear the "annoyingness" of this behaviour, sooner or later you will realise you won't need to skip the quotes/string...
